# How to match/pair random users in mobile app games?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, game-center, google-play-games

How to match/pair random users in mobile app games like DrawSomething and QuizUp

is there any sample resuable code available that can be integrated with respect to Gamecenter/Google Play Game Services.

Comment: You may find this helpful to get a good overview. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbYweTLvD-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty straight-forward process to randomly match up players.  The best place to start is the concept documentation: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer

then check out the samples on GitHub, especially the SkeletonTBMP.
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples